# What's the use of <> in Perl?

Tags: perl

What's the use of <> in Perl. How to use it ?
If we simply write

```
<>;
```

and

```
while(<>)
```

what is that the program doing in both cases?

Comment: I would say <> means "STDIN",input from prompt.

Comment: `<>` and `while(<>)` is explained in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (the latter is also explained in `perlvar`). `<>` is called the "null file handle". It is a *special construct* and *does not* just mean `<STDIN>`.

Comment: @pst, `<>` is not a file handle, "null" or otherwise. It's an operator. Specifically, the `readline` operator. There's a reference to it as the "angle operator" in perlvar, although there isn't actually any such operator. The angle brackets are used by two operators: `readline` or `glob`. The operator depends on the contents of the brackets.

Comment: @ikegami I think "null" is not a good word in this context, as it carries some connotations from other languages that do not exist in perl. The latter phrase is better.

Comment: @ikegami That's weird. I'm afraid I don't remember it.

Comment: Note that this can be [dangerous](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=258980) when used with untrusted arguments (e.g. `script.pl *`)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answers above are all correct, but it might come across more plainly if you understand general UNIX command line usage. It is *very* common to want a command to work on multiple files. E.g.

```
ls -l *.c
```

The command line shell (bash et al) turns this into:

```
ls -l a.c b.c c.c ...
```

in other words, ls never see '*.c' unless the pattern doesn't match. Try this at a command prompt (not perl):

```
echo *
```

you'll notice that you do not get an *.

So, if the shell is handing you a bunch of file names, and you'd like to go through each one's data in turn, perl's <> operator gives you a nice way of doing that...it puts the next line of the next file (or stdin if no files are named) into $_ (the default scalar).

Here is a poor man's grep:

```
while(<>) {
   print if m/pattern/;
}
```

Running this script:

```
./t.pl *
```

would print out all of the lines of all of the files that match the given pattern.

```
cat /etc/passwd | ./t.pl
```

would use cat to generate some lines of text that would then be checked for the pattern by the loop in perl.

So you see, while(<>) gets you a very standard UNIX command line behavior...process all of the files I give you, or process the thing I piped to you.

Answer (score 20):

```
 <>;
```

is a short way of writing

```
 readline();
```

or if you add in the default argument,

```
 readline(*ARGV);
```

[`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) is an operator that reads a line from the specified file handle. Reading from the special file handle [`ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV) will read from `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty or from the concatenation of the files named by `@ARGV` if it's not.

---

As for

```
while (<>)
```

It's a syntax error. If you had

```
while (<>) { ... }
```

it get rewritten to

```
while (defined($_ = <>)) { ... }
```

And as previously explained, that means the same as

```
while (defined($_ = readline(*ARGV))) { ... }
```

That means it will read lines from (previously explained) `ARGV` until there are no more lines to read.

Answer (score 7):

It is called the diamond operator and feeds data from either stdin if ARGV is empty or each line from the files named in ARGV. This webpage http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/learn/ch06_02.htm explains it very well.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators):

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the
>   behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes
>   a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of
>   them. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each
>   file listed on the command line.

Comment: [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) [tools/languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Google is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases of programming with syntactical sugar like this, `Deparse` of [O](http://p3rl.org/O) is helpful to find out what's happening:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'while(<>){print 42}'
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print 42;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 2):

it takes the STDIN standard input:

```
> cat temp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;
my $count=<>;
print "$count"."\n";
>
```

below is the execution:

```
> temp.pl
3
3

>
```

so as soon as you execute the script it will wait till the user gives some input.
after `3` is given as input,it stores that value in `$count` and it prints the value in the next statement.

Comment: And if you buy now, we'll include a **lifetime** subscription to CPAN, at no additional charge!