# File redirection VS. command line arguments

Tags: perl, stdin, io-redirection

I have a perl script named `sort.pl` that takes in STDIN from some file like so:

```
while(<>){
 print;
}
```

and I have been thinking I need to pass in a file with redirection like this: `./sort.pl < wordlist` but it has come to my attention that `./sort.pl wordlist` also works.

Why is this the case? In other languages I usually have to specify between command line arguments and file redirection.

Comment: For why it reads files as commands line arguments I cannot explain it better than this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12275794/7780

As for why it reads from stdin, it is because when no arguments are given perl assumes stdin to be the current "file".

Comment: When you don't specify a file handle inside the *line input operator*, then you get the *diamond operator*.  Search for that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanted to read from STDIN then you'd use:

```
while(<STDIN>){
```

What you've actually used is:

```
while(<>){
```

Which means: read all lines, from all files listed in @ARGV *or* if @ARGV is empty, read from STDIN instead.