# Extract data from a binary file

Tags: perl

I have a binary file. I want extract all data from `$marker + $step` to `$marker` (or end of file).

Data example:

23 40 92 34 32 09 84 39 02 89 30 fe 90 38 `01 02 03 f1 f2` 00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 ff dd cc cc cc 22 80 ee `01 02 03 f1 f2` 00 00 00 22 33 44 56 23 40 92 34 32 dd cc cc 22 33 44 22 33 44 `01 02 03 f1 f2` 00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 FF FF FF 52 FF FF 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

It contains three blocks. I need:

#### 1

```
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 ff dd cc cc cc 22 80 ee
```

#### 2

```
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 23 40 92 34 32 dd cc cc 22 33 44 22 33 44
```

#### 3

```
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 FF FF FF 52 FF FF 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I never worked with binary files with Perl.

```
$filename     = $ARGV[0];
$marker       = \x01\x02\x03\xf1\xf2;
$step         = 3;
$count        = 0;

open $file
while <$file> {
  seek $marker;
  Go to forward +$step bytes;
  $count++
  print EXTFILE_.$count.'.dat' $_

  # Until do not seek new $marker or EOF
}
close file
```

As a result, I have to get three .dat files.

How can I realize this pseudocode? What would be some simple example?

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'")**. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I wouldn't use Perl for this task. Perl's design is strongly geared towards processing text files, rather than binary files. Still, if you really want to use Perl, you may find the description of handling binary files in this answer at stackoverflow.com useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23151926/441899

Comment: You should look at the `unpack` function. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Perl is entirely happy with binary files. Please explain.

Comment: Is that what the actual file contents look like (when you `cat` them to a terminal?) or is it the output of hexdump (`xxd -p`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl regular expressions are just as happy with binary data as with readable text, and binary files can be opened with a mode of `raw` to avoid translating line endings.

Here's a solution that reads the whole file into memory and scans it for the *marker* string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift;

my $binary = do {
  open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$fh>;
};

my $marker = "\x01\x02\x03\xf1\xf2";

while ( $binary =~ /$marker(.*?)(?=$marker|\z)/sg ) {
  my @hex = map { sprintf '%02X', $_ } unpack 'C*', $1;
  print "@hex\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 11 FF DD CC CC CC 22 80 EE
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 23 40 92 34 32 DD CC CC 22 33 44 22 33 44
00 00 00 22 33 44 56 77 22 FF FF FF 52 FF FF 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

If the file is huge, or if you simply prefer the idea, you could set the *input record separator* to the marker string. Then a `readline` operation on the file would fetch up to and including the next occurrence of the marker pattern in the file. It means that each record is being read along with the marker from the beginning of the *next* record, but as it's going to be removed anyway it doesn't matter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift;
my $marker = "\x01\x02\x03\xf1\xf2";

open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename or die $!;
local $/ = $marker;

<$fh>;  # Drop the data up to and including the first marker

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;       # Remove the marker string from the end, if any
  my @hex = map { sprintf '%02X', $_ } unpack 'C*';
  print "@hex\n";
}
```

The output is identical to that of the program above.

Though that doesn't work for the required output of the program. This program uses the second technique above but writes to a series of `EXTFILE.dat` files instead of dumping the hex data. Note that an open mode of `raw` is necessary again.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift // 'file.bin';
my $marker = "\x01\x02\x03\xf1\xf2";

open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename or die $!;
local $/ = $marker;
<$fh>;  # Drop the data up to and including the first marker

my $count;
while (my $record = <$fh>) {
  chomp $record;
  my $outfile = sprintf 'EXTFILE_%d.dat', ++$count;
  open my $out_fh, '>:raw', $outfile or die $!;
  print $out_fh $record;
  close $out_fh or die $!;
}
```

Comment: Great answer -  the emphasis on `open` and  `<:raw` shows how one can keep things simple by sort of side-stepping encoding. Is `@hex = map { sprintf '%02X', $_ } unpack 'C*', $1;` doing what xxd would do in Unix? In any case I take it this would work on Windows or any Unix or OS/X - I can't create an appropriate file to test it on Android :-)

Comment: @G.Cito:  [Here's a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxpzewzy0cw6msj/file.bin) to my test file that contains the binary data that the OP posted. Yes, it's pretty much like `xxd`. The `unpack 'C*'` converts the string into a list of numeric code points, and the `sprintf '%02X'` converts each number to a two-character hex string. Putting an array in a string, as in `"@hex\n"`, puts spaces between each element of the array, like `join ' ', @hex`

Comment: @G.Cito: How are you running Perl on Android?

Comment: Just using the CCTools version - much mucking about has proven `cpanm` and the like won't work without a patch to `perl` for a missing POSIX locale function on the system.  There is a patch (which may now be part of 5.20+?) but I'm unable to pull and build my own updated version so I'm hoping CCTools refreshes so `cpanm` , `reply` etc. become possibilities .

Comment: Thanks for the files.  I see now I either created my binary file incorrectly or mixed it up with an earlier incorrect attempt: when using a tools like `xxd -p -r` I see that the spaces were replaced with "0" and the file ended with an "a". How did you create `file.bin` ?

Comment: @G.Cito: Perl. Pretty much the inverse of the programs above. [Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/4pvN0JMn)